Compositions of even n into even numbers greater than 2
I’m trying to determine an algorithm (or ideally a formula $f(n, k)$) to calculate the number of compositions of even integers, $n$, from 4 to 34 where each term is an even integer greater than 4 for each $k$.
So
$$
\begin{align}
f(4, 1) &= 1 [4]\\
f(6, 1) &= 1 [4]\\
f(8, 1) &= 1 [8]\\
f(8, 2) &= 1 [4+4]\\
f(10, 1) &= 1 [10]\\
f(10, 2) &= 2 [4+6,6+4]\\
\end{align}
$$
I believe this is equivalent to finding the compositions of all integers from 2 to 16 that don’t include 1 by simply dividing everything by 2?

I don't understand the notation.  What is $f(n,k)$?  What does, e.g., $1[4]$ mean?  Why is $f(6,1)=1[4]$?  That would seem to be a typo?  I think I'd understand it if you wrote $f(6,1)=1[6]$, though it is still bad notation.

last row : $f(10,2)=n$ means there is $n$ ways to write $10$ as a sum of $2$ even numbers greater than 2, and those $n=2$ ways are $4+6$ or $6+4$.

Yes, you can divide everything by 2, but $\frac{34}{2}$ is $17$,not $16$.

@Lourrran no, it means there are 2 [$f(n, k)$] ways of writing 10 [$n$] using 2 [$k$] summands and those $f(10, 2)=2$ ways are $4+6$ or $6+4$

You're interested in ways you can add $k$ elements of the set $A = \{\color{blue}{4,6,8, \dots, 32,34}\}$ to add up to some $n$. So now consider the following sum:
$$
\left(\sum_{i \in A}  x^{i} \right)^k=  \left(x^{\color{blue}{4}} +  x^{\color{blue}{6}} + \dots x^{\color{blue}{34}}\right)^k
$$
If we start expanding the product, each term in the resulting sum will be the result of choosing one of the $17$ terms in each of the $k$ sums being multiplied, and then multiplying those $k$ terms. For example, in $\left(\sum_{i \in A}  x^{i} \right)^3$ after expanding we'll have a term $x^4 \cdot x^{20} \cdot x^{12}$ which is obtained by mutliplying the $x^4$ from the first sum with the $x^{20}$ term from the second sum and the $x^{12}$ term from the third sum. Also notice that this is a different term than $x^4 \cdot x^{12} \cdot x^{20}$, which will also appear but is choosing the numbers $12$ and $20$ from different sums. So different orderings of the same product appear as distinct terms.
Now we ask what's the coefficient of $x^n$ after expanding $\left(\sum_{i \in A}  x^{i} \right)^k$? Since we group all the terms with the same exponent, then this number corresponds to all the different ways to add $k$ numbers in $A$ to give $n$, which is exactly the function you're looking for. Continuing the example, the coefficient of $x^{36}$ in the expansion of $\left(\sum_{i \in A}  x^{i} \right)^3$ will be at least $2$, since we know the $2$ terms $x^4 \cdot x^{20} \cdot x^{12}$ and $x^4 \cdot x^{12} \cdot x^{20}$ appear.
To extract the coefficient of $x^n$ you only need to differentiate $n$ times, divide by $n!$ and evaluate at $0$, since the differentiation eliminates all terms with exponent less than $n$, and evaluating at $0$ eliminates all terms with exponent greater than $n$. We thus obtian that
$$
f(n,k) = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} \left(\sum_{i \in A}  x^{i} \right)^k \Bigg\vert_{x=0} = \boxed{\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} \left(\sum_{j =2}^{17}  x^{2j} \right)^k \Bigg\vert_{x=0}}
$$
from where you can easily see that replacing $2j$ with $j$ and $n$ with $\frac{n}{2}$ does indeed give the same result.

There's also a recursive way to get to $f(n,k)$, which satisfies
$$
f(n,k) = \sum_{i \in A}f(n-i, k-1)
$$
To see why, take $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k =n$ some ordered $k$-sum. Notice now that $x_1 + x_2 +\dots +x_{k-1} = n-x_k$ is an ordered $k-1$-sum that adds up to $n- x_k$. This means that each $k$-sum of $n$ corresponds uniquely (because of order) to one $k-1$ sum of $n- x_k$. Adding them all up this gives the desired formula.
For an example, we can use this to calculate $f(10,2)$ as follows
$$
f(10,2) = f(6, 1) + f(4,1) + \underbrace{f(2,1) + f(0,1) + f(-2,1) + \dots + f(-24,1)}_{0} = 1+1 = 2
$$

If you want to use a calculator, here's a Mathematica code for the function
f[n_, k_] := (1/n!)*D[Sum[x^(2*i), {i, 2, 17}]^k, {x, n}] /. {x -> 0}

Which outputs as so

